# Android Studio Gradle: Connection timed out с указанными прокси

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proxy

Не могу запустить build gradle в сети компании, выдает ошибку "ERROR: Connection refused: connect". Proxy настроено, Android Studio даже скачал после установки библиотеки. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя в настройках делаю проверку для [адреса](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выдает connection есть,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но вот при сборке gradle не собирается. Знаю что есть systemProp.http.**** но у меня только Automatic proxy configuration. Как можно указать этот скрипт для gradle.

Выдает `Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.`
его я могу даже даже открыть в браузере и она скачивается

Код build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: не закоментировано только эти 
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
kotlin.code.style=official

Comment: А в Global gradle.properties ничего не активно

Comment: buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Это пустой проект, только создал в android studio

Comment: Добавил, в вопрос

Comment: с виду все нормально, есть допущение что ваш антивирус или что-то другое блокирует android studio доступ к сети и поэтому такое происходит, проверьте есть ли студия в белом списке

Comment: Обновил вопрос, там есть картинки, где я проверяю connection, все ок

Comment: Мне каждется надо указать proxy script для gradle, только как я не знаю. Знаю что можно указать прокси с адресом портом и пользователем но как можно указать script адрес который указан в Auto detect proxy settings in AS

Comment: добавил ответ, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста

Comment: Возможно, это хитрый баг. Столкнулся с такой же проблемой пару дней назад - на рабочем ноуте не мог соединиться дома из-за прокси, хотя дома никакого прокси нет. Проблему не решил.